# What does it mean to "disable SameSite for some components"?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, openid-connect, samesite, ws-federation

In the [ASP.NET documentation about SameSite cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite), is says (bold mine):

> Some forms of authentication like OpenID Connect (OIDC) and WS-Federation default to POST based redirects. The POST based redirects trigger the SameSite browser protections, so **SameSite is disabled for these components**.

What does it mean that SameSite is disabled for these components? That those cookies are blocked by the browser? Or that the browser protections are somehow disabled?

Comment: Probably it means that the cookies are issued with `SameSite=None` (instead of `Lax`), thereby circumventing the mechanisms by which browsers would suppress them.